# Error opening block StreamChunkId : BlockNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am getting some transient excepting in using spark-streaming with Amazon Kinesis with storage level "MEMORY_AND_DISK_2". We are using Spark 2.2.0 with emr-5.9.0.

```
19/05/22 01:56:16 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error opening block StreamChunkId{streamId=438690479801, chunkIndex=0} for request from /10.1.100.56:38074
org.apache.spark.storage.BlockNotFoundException: Block broadcast_13287_piece0 not found
```

I have checked that are no lost nodes in EMR cluster. And HDFS utilization percentage is 35%

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause ?